# What's wrong with this algorithm code

Tags: probability

I don't know if I am in the right forum ! I am biginner in python.

Consider the function $g(x)=\dfrac{1}{1+x^2}$,  I have this code in python to approximate the area of integral with monté carlo method, I get zeros as results even if I change n.
Is there a mistake? Thank you in advance  :

````
import random
n=1000
c=0
for k in range(1,n+1):
    x=random.uniform(0,1)
    y=random.uniform(0,1)
    if y<=1/(1+x**2):
        c=c+1
    else:
        c=0          
f=c/n    
print(f)


```
````

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Remove the else clause.

Comment: Are you using Python 2? In that case `1/(1+x**2)` is a *truncating* integer division and evaluates to zero. This is a programming problem, not a mathematical.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a programming problem, not a mathematical problem.

Comment: This is for a python forum such as www.python-forum.io

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't say over which interval you are integrating.  So it is impossible to determine whether your code is computing the area you actually want.  Based on your code, I assume you want 
$$  \int_0^1 \frac{1}{x^2 + 1} \,\mathrm{d}x = \frac{\pi}{4} = 0.785{\dots}  \text{.}  $$

In Python 2.7.15+, I also get zero from your code.

Change 1:
We don't want to reset `c` to zero every time we get a point outside the area.  We just don't increment `c`.

```
import random
n=1000
c=0
for k in range(1,n+1):
    x = random.uniform(0,1)
    y = random.uniform(0,1)
    if y <= 1/(1 + x**2):
        c=c+1
    else:
        c=c+0        # Change 1
f=c/n
print(f)
```

still gives zero.  Why?  Let's see what `c` and `n` were just before computing `f`.

```
import random
n=1000
c=0
for k in range(1,n+1):
    x = random.uniform(0,1)
    y = random.uniform(0,1)
    if y <= 1/(1 + x**2):
        c=c+1
    else:
        c=c+0        # Change 1
print(c, ", ", n)    # What is going into `f`?
f=c/n
print(f)
```

Here we find out `c` is $794$ and `n` is $1000$.  Both have integral type, so in Python 2, `c/n` is zero because for integer arguments, `/` returns the quotient in [the division algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algorithm).  Here, that quotient is $0$ and the remainder is $794$.  If either or both divisor and dividend are floating point numbers, `/` performs floating point division.  If you wanted the division algorithm for floating points also, you would use `//`.  So we need to [make our division be a floating point division](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267869/how-can-i-force-division-to-be-floating-point-division-keeps-rounding-down-to-0).  I'll use the (currently) second answer there: coerce either argument to a float.

Change #2:

```
import random
n=1000
c=0
for k in range(1,n+1):
    x = random.uniform(0,1)
    y = random.uniform(0,1)
    if y <= 1/(1 + x**2):
        c=c+1
    else:
        c=c+0        # Change 1
f=c/float(n)         # Change 2
print(f)
```

This gives the output `0.779`, which is an approximation to the correct answer.

If I set $n = 1000000$, I get $0.784829$, which does agree with the correct answer to the precision we can expect for this $n$ ([relative error proportional to](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_integration) $n^{-1/2}$).

There are additional improvements:

- When the point is outside the area, we need not update `c`, so remove the `else: c=c+0`.
- I observe a 10% speedup using `c+=1` over `c=c+1`.  Tested via a few repetitions of each of

  ```
  python -m timeit 'c=10; c+=1'
  ```

  and

  ```
  python -m timeit 'c=10; c=c+1'
  ```
- Which is faster `y < ...` or `y <= ...`?

  ```
  python -m timeit 'x=y=0.1; y < 1/(1 + x**2)'

  python -m timeit 'x=y=0.1; y <= 1/(1 + x**2)'
  ```

  No discernible difference.
- Which is faster `x**2` or `x*x`?

  ```
  python -m timeit 'x=y=0.1; y <= 1/(1 + x**2)'

  python -m timeit 'x=y=0.1; y <= 1/(1 + x*x)'
  ```

  `x*x` by 10-40% in repeated testing.

Making the choices that are evidently faster carves about 10% off the run time.  The last version of the code that I used is

```
import random
n=1000000
c=0
for _ in range(n):
    x = random.uniform(0,1)
    y = random.uniform(0,1)
    if y <= 1/(1 + x*x):
        c+=1

print(c/float(n))
```

Changes:

- [Underscore variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893163/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-single-underscore-variable-in-python).
- Shortened `range()` because we don't actually care what values it takes.
- Removed trivial variable `f`.

Comment: Thank you very much, you're great.

Answer (score 0):

Your `else` clause ensures only additions since its last invocation will count towards $c$. By `c = 0`, you probably meant `c += 0`. But you don't need the `else` clause at all.

Comment: I remove else, but I get the same result : 0.

Comment: @FHA It worked for me, but I used Python 3, where `5/2` is equal to `2.5`. If it's `2` for you, it's because you're using Python 2. Try changing `1/` to `1.0/` & `c/n` to `c/float(n)`.